# Calling system() inside a C loop fails

Tags: c, system, errno

I am trying to write a simple C code which executes a shell script for N iterations (where N is larger than 3000). Initially, the code seems to work perfectly well but as the number of iterations increases, system() function starts returning -1. Also, if I run the entire program once again, the error occurs at exactly the same point in the loop.

Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char command[] = "bash sampleScript";
    int i, ret, N = 3000;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){

       /* Open 'sampleScript', make the required modifications and close it */

       while(!system(NULL)){
          printf("Shell is unavailable");
          sleep(2);
       }
       ret = system(command);
       if(ret == -1){
          printf("System failed\n");
          exit(1);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the shell script does not affect the C code. When I execute this code, around i = 2900, system() starts returning -1 and I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. Am I missing an obvious point here? Can someone help me out?

I use gcc on 64-bit Ubuntu.

**Update:**

When system() returns -1, the corresponding `errno` value is 12 - Cannot allocate memory.

The output of ulimit -a is

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 47495
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 47495
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: look at `errno`, that should give you a hint. Does `sampleScript` call any backgound processes? 'too many processes' might occur in that case

Comment: In addition to Ingo's recommendations, the output of `ulimit -a` might also be useful.

Comment: `while(!system(NULL)) { ... }` -- If the shell is unavailable, it's not likely to become available later.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you issue,maybe you can use `printf("system failed when i =%d\n",i);` to get some information

I use SUSE .

ulimit -a print this:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7464
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 7464
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Here is my code(problem is no error print,N is 10000 now!) :

```
 2 #define N 10000

  3 int main(void)
  4 {
  5     char command[] = "cd";
  6     int i, ret;
  7 
  8     for(i=0;i<N;i++){
  9 
 10        /* Open 'sampleScript', make the required modifications and close it */
 11 
 12        while(!system(NULL)){
 13           printf("Shell is unavailable");
 14          // sleep(2);
 15        }
 16        ret = system(command);
 17        if(ret == -1){
 18           printf("System failed\n");
 19           exit(1);
 20        }
 21     }
 22     return 0;
 23 }
```